# traffic manager + azure website : how do I configure custom dns ssl

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I have a custom dns entry mapped to my traffic manager setup via CNAME record.  I also have traffic manager pointing to my azure website endpoint and I have a wildcard cert matching my custom dns uploaded on my website.  I'm having trouble getting ssl to work.  The documentation is not clear on how to set up SSL when using traffic manager.  Any help is appreciated.  Please note I had this working with cloud service "web role" but I'm wanting to migrate to azure websites.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not having any problems getting your custom domain name to work, correct? You're just having problems with getting your SSL?

Comment: I've purchased a custom SSL for my custom domain and I applied to my custom domain with SNI SSL in the Azure Portal. Must it be IP based SSL? What I do is at the Domain Provider provides the CNAME record instead of A record. I got this error when I load the XXXglobal.trafficmanager.net. It stated that the server could not prove that it is XXXglobal.trafficmanager.net; its security certificate is from *.XXX.p.azurewebsites.net. Any advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen this blog post by Scott Hanselman? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CloudPowerHowToScaleAzureWebsitesGloballyWithTrafficManager.aspx

You don't upload the certificate to traffic manager. You upload it and set it up for each of the individual sites that the traffic manager will route your customers to