# Can a Domain Name purchased through another vendor be used with an SSL Certificate purchased from Azure?

Tags: azure, ssl, domain-name

We purchased a domain name from Network Solutions, and set up our website as two App Services in Azure (one within US East and one within US West). Our domain name purchased from Network Solutions is assigned as a hostname in Azure, and a traffic manager balances the traffic between the two App Services. I have two questions...

1. Azure offers SSL Certficates. If I purchase an SSL Certificate from Azure, is there anything I need to do in Network Solutions to update the site?
2. Do I need to purchase two SSL Certificates since I am using two App Services?

I have looked at these articles, but unfortunately, they did not answer my questions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing the both the AppServices serve the same application and are accessible via a single domain (e.g. mywebsite.com). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you already have a custom domain associated with your Web Apps (both deployments Region #1 and #2), then no. You're all set.
   E.g. `www.example.com` pointing to `{TrafficManagerName}.trafficmanager.net`
2. No. Just one TLS certificate valid for `www.example.com` or `*.example.com`
   See my answer here for more:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/40399500/4148708